# Only using 2 cores instead of 4

Tags: system, cpu

I have installed elementary OS 5 and when i run `lscpu` i see only 2 CPUcores working instead of 4.
I have notebook Asus E203N. Any ideas to solve it ??

Comment: Take a look here maybe, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468766/understanding-output-of-lscpu

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/es/es/ark/products/95598/intel-celeron-processor-n3350-2m-cache-up-to-2-4-ghz.html) your CPU? If that's the case you only have 2 cores not 4.
Otherwise update your question with your CPU model.

I doubt your laptop has it, but some computers allow to unblock the CPU to have more cores or to enable hyperthreading. Check inside the bios/firmware to see if there's such option.